# Webpack 4 compiled less/css has wrong order

Tags: javascript, webpack, less, webpack-style-loader

I have a `style.less` which imports css and less files as follows:

```
@import './less/bootstrap.less';
@import './css/workflowMap.css';
```

In the compiled file i have an inverted output ( first workflowMap.css then bootstrap.less)

My webpack configuration is the following:

```
    {
        test: /\.(le|c)ss$/,

        use: [
            "style-loader",
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            "css-loader",
            {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: {
                    plugins: loader => [require("autoprefixer")]
                }
            },
            {
                loader: "less-loader",
                options: {
                    modifyVars : { ...globalVars },
                    paths: [...paths]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: You should be using separate rules for CSS and LESS since they require different loaders/loader orders. CSS only needs `css-loader` and LESS needs `less-loader` then `css-loader`.

Comment: @Adam doesn't working. In both cases ( css/less rules )  i still need `style-loader`, `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` ... but i don't understand where i wrong